# javascript get only asked params inside function as arguments

Tags: javascript

I know we can get all arguments in javascript inside function when it is called anywhere . we can get extra arguments which we didnt asked also .
But can we get only asked arguments on javascript function?
Like :

```
function a(a,b){
 console.log(arguments);
}
```

if we call function a somewhere `a(1,2,3,4,5)`
then the output will be like `[1,2,3,4,5]`

but i want only `[1,2]` as i have expected only two params in function?

My condition is

```
    index: (req, res, next) => {
            var params =  ['batch_id', 'section_id', 'subject_id', 'term', 'assesment_id', 'assesment_type'];
            var _ = req._;
            req.utils.requestValidation([req,res,next], params,'query')
// But i dont want to send params like above always instead like below
 req.utils.requestValidation(arguments, params,'query')
```

and where it is called is

```
requestValidation: (data, options, param) => {
        if (!options) return;
        var _ = data[0]._ || data._;
        var rules = {};

        var data = {};
        var sanity = {};
        var elr = [validator.escape, validator.ltrim, validator.rtrim];
        options.map((item, index) => {
            rules[item] = 'required';
            sanity[item] = elr;
        });
        data[param] = sanity;
        if (typeof data != 'string') {
            sanitizer.setOptions(data);
            var data = sanitizer.sanitize(data[0], data[1], data[2],param);
            return data[0].validation.validate(rules, data[0][param]);
        }
        return data.validation.validate(rules, data[param]);
    },
```

Comment: why not simply use them using variables a and b directly? Rest will be automatically ignored

Comment: i want some automation ..

Comment: huhh? elaborate please

Comment: You cannot automate declaration to begin with, so what would be the point?

Comment: @SamundraKC Do any of these answers help you? If so, please accept them.

Comment: @torazaburo no i didn't find any answer that meet my requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you need only two parameters just cut `arguments` to two items

if you want automatic this you can write function-wrapper, something like this:

```
function wrapperCutParams(func, paramsCount){
  return function(){
    var args = Array.prototype.slice(arguments, 0);
    if(args.length > paramsCount){
      args = args.slice(0, paramsCount)
    }
    func.apply(this, args)
  }
}
```

Then

```
var a = function a(a,b){
 console.log(arguments);
}

a = wrapperCutParams(a, 2)
```

Or just

```
a = wrapperCutParams(function a(a,b){
     console.log(arguments);
    }, 2)
```

Comment: While this will surely work I don't find it neither readable nor maintainable nor easily debuggable nor, last but not least, automated

Comment: Why would I need to pass in `paramsCount`, when it is already available as `func.length`?

Comment: @torazaburo I show just example how it can be. But  `func.length` is  a good point

Comment: @imbalind at least it is automated :)  I know `Samundra KC` desire is a weird by itself  and seems there are should be another solution for whole problem. But, can you propose another way of restricting number of parameters? As for me in any case there will be some function creator that will implicitly insert check for parameters. The way how it will be implemented may differ

Comment: Your solution is fine. You just need to tweak it to take `paramsCount` from `func.length` instead of passing it in explicitly. Also, I don't really see the need for the `args.length > paramsCount` check. By the way, I don't think the OP's desire is particularly weird. It could be a good idea in some cases as a matter of defensive programming to ensure that no more arguments are passed than are declared.

Comment: @imbalind you mean that we don't need to set number of parameters? In this case yes.

Answer (score 1):

Since you declared those arguments the most readable way would be to use them as they are, if you need to put them in an array, just do it.

```
myArgs = [a, b];
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a higher-order function which takes the underlying function as a parameter, and returns a function which truncates the argument list to the number of arguments the function is asking for, based on its `length` property.

```
function slice_args(fn) {
  return function() {
    return fn.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0, fn.length));
  };
}
```

Then

```
function a(a,b){
  console.log(arguments);
}

var b = slice_args(a);

b(1,2,3,4,5)
> [1, 2]
```